# SharePoint 2010 client javascript code from dialog box page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I am using code in an aspx page (javascript) that is displayed using the sharepoint 2010 UI framework dialog functions.

However, it throws an error. I can't get at the exact details. But here's the code

function DoReject(rejectype) {

```
    rejecttype = rejectype;


    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Applications');
```

var qs =window.location.search.substring(1);
        var arrs = qs.substring(0,qs.indexOf('&',0)).replace('arr=','').split(',');

```
    for (var i = 0; i < arrs.length;i++) {
        k = arrs[i];
        if (k != null && k != '') {
            try {

                this.applicant = targetList.getItemById(k);
                applicant.set_item('ApplicationStatus', 'REJECTED');
                applicant.update();
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.doNothingReject), Function.createDelegate(this, this.rejectError));

                this.applicant = targetList.getItemById(k);
                clientContext.load(applicant, 'EMail', 'CrisDBID', 'ApplyJobTitle', 'JobRef', 'BrandId');
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.DoRejectSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.rejectError2));
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Note i haven't included the success / error methods, as they are superfluous in this.  And the ids return correctly - they are passed into the query string. So the variable k is definitely the id of the list item.

In the error event rejectError, I use the signature

rejectError(e)

Does anyone know how to get the error details from the parameter / whats wrong with the code?

is it possible to call list operations on a page that isn't the native list page using the javascript object model?

thanks in advance
M

Answer (score 0):

What browser do you get the error in? Is the error consistent between browsers? I would recommend that you debug the javascript and look at the variables at the line before it fails to see what's going on.

On a side note the first snippet you pasted looks like a standard train-wreck so if the code fails there it's likely one of these are `undefined` (if clientContext, get_web() or get_lists() does not return a value). I don't know anything about Sharepoint UI framework so  "list operation" etc doesn't say much to me.